# Problema al hacer menú en java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un menu de ejemplo para mi proyecto, peor tengo problemas a la hora de salir de la aplicación.

Cuando ejecuto mi menú me sale al final también el mensaje de salida.

¿Que tengo que cambiar de mi menú para que me salga de la aplicación y me muestre su mensaje de salida cuando pulse el boton 0?.

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean salir = false;
     int dato = 0;

      System.out.println("============================================\n"
              + "      =====Gestión de Videojuegos=====\n"
              + "============================================");

       do {
  System.out.println(""
            +"1.- Añadir un videojuego.\n"
            +"2.- Listar videojuegos.\n"
            +"3.- Borrar un videojuego.\n"
            +"4.- Guardar datos en fichero.\n"
            +"5.- Recuperar datos desde fichero.\n"
            +"\n"
            +"0.- Salir de la aplicación.\n"
            +"============================================="
            );
  switch(dato){
      case 1:
          break;
      case 2:
          break;
      case 3:
          break;
      case 4:
          break;
      case 5:
          break;
      case 0:
           System.out.println("Gracias por usar nuestro gestor de videojuegos\n"
               + "           ===Aplicación cerrada===");
          break;

  }

       }while(0!=dato);


     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aplica el siguiente código, te lo he arreglado más o menos para lo que necesitas:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

     boolean salir = false;
     int dato = 0;

      System.out.println("============================================\n"
              + "      =====Gestión de Videojuegos=====\n"
              + "============================================");

       do {
  System.out.println(""
            +"1.- Añadir un videojuego.\n"
            +"2.- Listar videojuegos.\n"
            +"3.- Borrar un videojuego.\n"
            +"4.- Guardar datos en fichero.\n"
            +"5.- Recuperar datos desde fichero.\n"
            +"\n"
            +"0.- Salir de la aplicación.\n"
            +"============================================="
            );

  try{
      System.out.println("Selecciona una opción");
      dato = lector.nextInt();
      lector.nextLine();
  }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("No se ha seleccionado ninguna opción");
  }
  switch(dato){
      case 1:
          break;
      case 2:
          break;
      case 3:
          break;
      case 4:
          break;
      case 5:
          break;
      case 0:
           System.out.println("Gracias por usar nuestro gestor de videojuegos\n"
               + "           ===Aplicación cerrada===");
          break;

  }

   }while(0!=dato);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Hola barraca96, muchas gracias por tu aporte, se me ha pasado por completo el scanner para que me lea el número que voy a introducir.

Answer (score 1):

Además de lo que comenta Pablo, debes incluir el código necesario para que tu aplicación lea el valor deseado desde el teclado:

```
//antes del menú    
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//antes del switch    
dato = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Al inicializar la variable `dato` con un 0, una vez que el programa lleva al `switch` se va a cumplir siempre la condición `dato==0`, con lo que se va a mostrar siempre la cadena de salida.
Para corregirlo, inicializa la variable `dato` con un valor que no se use, como por ejemplo -1:

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean salir = false;
     int dato = -1;

      System.out.println("============================================\n"
              + "      =====Gestión de Videojuegos=====\n"
              + "============================================");

       do {
  System.out.println(""
            +"1.- Añadir un videojuego.\n"
            +"2.- Listar videojuegos.\n"
            +"3.- Borrar un videojuego.\n"
            +"4.- Guardar datos en fichero.\n"
            +"5.- Recuperar datos desde fichero.\n"
            +"\n"
            +"0.- Salir de la aplicación.\n"
            +"============================================="
            );
  switch(dato){
      case 1:
          break;
      case 2:
          break;
      case 3:
          break;
      case 4:
          break;
      case 5:
          break;
      case 0:
           System.out.println("Gracias por usar nuestro gestor de videojuegos\n"
               + "           ===Aplicación cerrada===");
          break;

  }

       }while(0!=dato);


     }

 }
```

Comment: Hola pablo, si hago eso entro en un bucle infinito, yo lo que quiero hacer es que cuando pulse el boton 0 el programa me salga de la apliación, es decir que mi menu me pida un número y si es el 0 me salga

Comment: Es que te falta el código para recoger valores